# Clear the Activity stack when I go to an activity

Tags: android

I am working on an application with several Activities, problem is that I want the user to be able to log out by pressing a button.

Suppose we have 4 Activity named A,B,C,D. Navigation of the activity like B->C->D.

On Activity D user have options for logout. When user click on the Logout button the he go to Activity A which is not called in the navigation. Now, user click on the back button then he got to previous activity like Activity D.

I already tried to launch the Activity with the two following flags:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, LoginActivity.class);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);        
startActivity(intent);
```

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Okay, I made myself a small project to somewhat simulate what you have. I'm going to leave out the imports in the code below. Also, read all the code and comments, I didn't write them to have you skip over them. Let's call the classes splash, login, page1, page2, and page3. In your splash class, before the onCreate() method, let's put a few things.

```
package com.test.jeets;

public class splash extends Activity {

    //Add all of these right here!
    public static boolean loggedin = false;
    public static int sdk = new Integer(Build.VERSION.SDK).intValue();

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.splash);
        //This is your splash screen, all the code goes here!
    }
}
```

Now that's your splash screen! Done! For the login screen, we'll want to make sure it can't go back to the splash screen, and instead exit out of the app when back is pressed. That's easy! Let's just override the back button and use `moveTaskToBack(true)`.

```
package com.test.jeets;

public class login extends Activity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.login);

        //This is the login page stuff. Nothing special needs done here.
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)  {
        if (splash.sdk < 5 && keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK && event.getRepeatCount() == 0) {
            onBackPressed();
        }

        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }
    //This will make the back button exit the app to the home screen.
    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        moveTaskToBack(true);
        return;
    }
    //If the user leaves the app from the login screen while not logged in, they are returned to the splash screen.
    @Override
    public void onRestart() {
        super.onRestart();
        if(splash.loggedin == false){
        Intent i = new Intent(login.this, splash.class);
        startActivity(i);}
    }
}
```

Now, that's done! Let's go to your first page (the page you go to after you're logged in) and add a line in the `onCreate()` method

```
splash.loggedin = true;
```

You might want to consider having a user back out of this page log them out as well. Not necessary, but certainly do-able.

The last thing you'll need to do is set that variable to false when a user logs out with the logout button. So in the code for the button, before the call to start the login activity again, just add `splash.loggedin = false;`. Now when the button is clicked, it will log the user out, set the variable to false, and take them to the login screen. Like I said, I tested this with a simple layout and real basic switch between activities and it worked fine for me.

Comment: But in case of me, I have splash activity when I press back button on Login activity then I am able to out of application but when I again launch application then I do not see splash activity, I start at login activity. therefore I want to see splash screen when I launch application again. Please help me if you can give me another suggestion.

Comment: Added a bit at the end that should help.

Comment: I am not sure that how to use it. Please help me, I am facing this problem.

Comment: Now what we want is if they leave the app from the login screen, to come back to the splash screen. No matter when you leave from the login screen. Maybe the more appropriate thing would be:
`@Override
public void onPause(){
    Intent i = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, SplashScreen.class);
    startActivity(i);
}`

Comment: I'll put together an example once the SDK and ADT plugin install.

Comment: Thanks for reply, but this is not solution for me. When I leave the app I want to out of application not go to splash screen. But when I launch the application again then I want to go to splash screen. But in my case I got to login activity. Please help me.

Comment: Rewrote answer, answers your asked question as well as the added information from the comments. Don't forget to mark as answer.

Comment: It seems that you are very close to the scenario. In the case,I logout from application then I go to login activity and I pressed back then I go to out of application. When I launch the application again then I do not see Splash screen, I go to login screen.In my application user have a option that he can remember his username and password.

Comment: When user check the remember me option then he do not see login activity agian, he goes to direct home screen.And he do logout then he go to login activity. In this case login activity do not call in stack. Now login activity is the top activity and user press back then he go to out of application and again he launch application then he go to ligon activity. He do not see splash activity. I problem is only that when user launch application again then he want to see splash atcivity. Thanks for reply. Pls suggest me. And will not forget to mark when It problem solved.thx 4 giving precious time.

Comment: That's what the `onRestart()` method is for. Make sure whatever checks are in place to see that the user is logged out will set `splash.loggedin` to false. As long as `loggedin` is false, if the app starts on that activity it should load the splash activity. Can you upload your splash and login activity (get rid of any sensitive info on it) to somewhere like pastebin so I could look at it?

Comment: I am going to in loop for splash screen. Means spalsh screen are showing again and again. I have followed as long as you define.

Comment: Add `public static boolean test = false;` with loggedin, and on the logout button have it do `splash.test = true;`. Change the `onRestart()` to `if(splash.loggedin == false && splash.test == true)` and then set `splash.test` to false. This would be easier if you could show me your code. Maybe edit your question to include some code?

[Here](http://www.mediafire.com/?384hn0ynylrmho3) is my example code.

Comment: I still do not see splash activity. Please help me.

Comment: Could you zip up your project file and upload it somewhere so I can see your code? If you want, go ahead and delete anything that accesses anything you want to keep private. All I need to see is the code for the splash screen, the code for the login screen, and the code for the logout button.

Answer (score 3):

Please try this in your Activity D logout event.

```
 Button button=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btnLogout);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
```

`@Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Intent intent=new Intent(context,ActivityA.class);
            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
            context.startActivity(intent);

        }
    });</PRE>`

Comment: I have tried it. If you have another options then please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
```

You remove FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK by the second call.

Comment: Thanks for reply, but it's not working.Do you have another solution?

Comment: That works for me... I start a dashboard activity with the same flags.

Comment: It's not working for me, when I pressed back button then I go to not logout Activity but its priviuos activity. If you have another solution please reply me.

Answer (score 1):

Finally this code is working for me.......

When I press back button on Login activity then I go to Home screen of android device.

`Intent intent= new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(intent);`